# Citrus SplitPay: How to integrate Split pay in mobile application

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing, citrus-pay, citrus-framework

I have created sample merchant user in the Citrus. But I didnt know how to approach it for SplitPay. Consider my scenario , I have created shopping app for my client. I need to get some % as a commission and remaining amt will be sent to my client.

kindly advise me how to approach this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating SplitPay requires you to use cURL APIs in your code to

1. Authenticate the merchant - [User-Authentication API](https://developers.citruspay.com/documentation/payment-stack/splitpay/user-authentication/)
2. Let the merchant create, update, get seller details and account balances - [Seller API](https://developers.citruspay.com/documentation/payment-stack/splitpay/adding-sellers/)
3. Merchants be able to add, get and update transaction and transaction split details - [Transaction API](https://developers.citruspay.com/documentation/payment-stack/splitpay/transactions-api/)
4. Let the merchant split the transaction between sellers - [Split API](https://developers.citruspay.com/documentation/payment-stack/splitpay/split/)
5. Get merchant account details - [Merchant API](https://developers.citruspay.com/documentation/payment-stack/splitpay/merchant-apis/)
6. Provide transaction settlement details after settlement transaction - [Settlement API](https://developers.citruspay.com/documentation/payment-stack/splitpay/settlement-api/)
7. Let the merchant release funds to the seller account - [Transaction Release Fund API](https://developers.citruspay.com/documentation/payment-stack/splitpay/transactions-release-funds/)
8. Make refunds on SplitPay - [SplitPay Refunds API](https://developers.citruspay.com/documentation/payment-stack/splitpay/splitpay-refunds/)

You can implement the cURL APIs in whichever language your backend is in. 
Need more help? Drop a mail at developer.support@citruspay.com